# Удаление div из строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Каким образом из **строки**:

```
<div class="messages">тут может быть все что угодно</div>
<div class="messages">тут может быть все что угодно<div id="test"></div></div>
<div class="messages">тут может быть все что угодно</div>
```

можно удалить  первый `<div class="messages">`?

Прошу заметить, что именно из строки, а не из `DOM`.

Comment: А если будет первым `<div class="messages">тут может быть все что угодно<div id="test"></div></div>`? Всё-таки, DOM упростит задачу.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так, с помощью регулярных выражений. Если нужно удалить все, можете добавить модификатор **g** в регулярное выражение.

```js
var t = "<div>Тест1</div> <div>Тест2</div><div>Тест3</div>";

function replaceDiv(markup) {
  return markup.replace(/<div[^>]*?>[\s\S]*?<\/div>/i, '');
}

var replaced = replaceDiv(t);

alert(replaced);
```

Если требуется именно убрать из строки все совпадения с class=messages, то требуется сделать изменения в регулярном выражении:

```
<div.*(class="messages")[^>]*?>[\s\S]*?<\/div>
```

Comment: Из строки нужно убрать только первый div #messages. И в этом диве может быть овер много других дивов и элементов.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте строку преобразовать в массив по разделителю переноса строки (если, конечно он там есть); удалить первый элемент массива и обратно собрать массив в строку.

Например:

```
let array = domString.split('\n');
array.splice(0,1);
array.join('\n')
```

UPD
Или другой вариант: преобразовать строку в дом дерево. Из дерева привычными методами удалить не нужные элементы. Вывести обратно в строку

Comment: Не выйдет так. Так в messages может и 1 и 2 и 20 дивов быть, с "хаотичными переносами". Привязка должна быть именно к классу дива.